# interpreting negative square root of a matrix

Tags: matrices, geometry, matrix-equations

I am working on stability analysis of systems with impacts and in my algorithm, I have reached a state where I have $xPx = 1$, where $P$ is a positive semi definite matrix. now with my code, at a point, I calculate the value of P, I want to recover x, which will be $sqrt(1/P)$. But as there are some negative elements of P the square root is coming imaginary number which cannot be right as my $x$ is a position variable in transverse plane. Whats is the solution or am I making some mathematical logical error?
equation is from following paper, equation number 14.

[click here for link to paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.2247.pdf)

Thanks for help.

Comment: To take the square root of a matrix you need to know its eigenvalues. These need to be positive (or zero) to get a matrix of real entries. The matrix itself need not have all positive entries.

Comment: OK, in my case I have positive eigenvalues. Can you direct me as to how I can calculate the square root with this, I searched on wiki, but couldnt find any procedure. Matlab is giving me imaginary outputs.

Comment: If the eigenvalues are different and non-zero. Find the corresponding eigenvectors. Create the matrix U whose columns are the eigenvectors. Calculate the inverse matrix $U^{-1}$. If D is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues (in the same order as the columns of eigenvectors in U) then your P matrix is $UDU^{-1}$ and the square root of P is $UD^{\frac{1}{2}}U^{-1}$. Here, the square root of D is done by simply square rooting the diagonal eigenvalues. The square root of the inverse of P is obtained by replacing the square root of the eigenvalues by their inverse values. This  is diagonalization.

Comment: The Matlab command [U,D] = eig(P) will give you U and D.

Comment: Great thanks, Paul :)